# Connecting to a s3 bucket from docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I am building a docker container which, in a specific folder transform some data, I would like to allocate those files in a s3 bucket, within as specific folder. I have been going thought the aws cli documentation but not sure how this needs to be faced it.

I have installed it without errors by using:

```
# AWS cli isntallation
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        python3 \
        py3-pip \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && pip3 install \
        awscli \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
 
RUN aws --version
```

I have read about adding the yaml configuration to point to the bucket but not sure how the process needs to be done. Someone with similar project on mind which can point me better to some documentation or how to face it as i am very layman in docker.

Comment: I'd recommend using a language-native SDK over the AWS CLI tool if it's at all an option.  Also note that getting correct credentials into a container can be tricky; arguably the best approach is if you can run the container on an EC2 instance with its own IAM instance profile and then the container can use the instance's credentials.